# Unable to Activate My Virtual Environment Because Activate File Not Showing Up

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

So I installed venv for python and made a virtual environment called ftai_venv. However when I activate it I get an error

[image]

When I go into ftai_venv/bin, I don't see the activate bash file. Where would I get this?

Answer (score 0):

The file should be there have you tried creating another virtual environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands to create the virtual environment
On macOS and Linux:

python3 -m venv ftai_venv

source ftai_venv/bin/activate

[for more detail check the link](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: I get an error saying "Error: Unable to create directory '/path/to/ftai_venv/bin/activate"